# How to manage your remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I am leasing a server from 1and1, and they tell me the way to administer it is through Remote Desktop:

All details are listed under Server Access Data in your 1and1 Control Panel.  Remote desktop is running by default and responding:

```
$ telnet 74.208.12.121 3389
Trying 74.208.12.121...
Connected to 74.208.12.121.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

So my question is, is logging into the remote desktop, is that like having a separate computer in addition to my laptop?  Do I have to download asp.net 4.0 just like I did to my laptop?  How do I FTP web files to this server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I lease my own server, do I need remote desktop or Parallels Small Business Panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222301/if-i-lease-my-own-server-do-i-need-remote-desktop-or-parallels-small-business-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in that it is just like having another computer. You'll have to download any packages/libraries that your web site needs, unless they are bundled in the bin directory of the site when you deploy.

To transfer files, you shouldn't use ftp. Instead check the option "local drives" under "local resources" when setting up the remotde desktop connection. When you're connected, that will give you access to your local files so that you can copy files between your local machine and the server.

Comment: Thanks Anders .... I appreciate the information!  Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question!