# How do I transfer VS files to the server, via remote desktop?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manage your remote desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265688/how-to-manage-your-remote-desktop)

Now that I'm building a site via VS 2010 .... and I'm accessing it through remote desktop, how do I upload a file?   For instance, if I want to change default.aspx, how do I do this?

Thanks!vis

Comment: Anders answered this in one of your recent questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265688/how-to-manage-your-remote-desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These instructions works on a LAN Remote Desktop Connection, not tried on a WAN

- Launch the Remote Desktop client, but do not connect to another
  computer, instead click `Options`
- Click the `Local Resources` tab, then click `More`
- Expand the `Drives` category. Check the box next to the local hard disks needed on the remote computer, then click OK

Now connect to the remote computer and in the remote "My Computer" window you will find your local drives as shared.

Comment: this should work over any connection where RDP is being used.

Comment: @AndrewBarber thanks, was just setting up an environment to test.

Comment: :) I have one client server I RDP into over the Internet, and it works fine. Meant to say that with my first comment. heh. +1 too, btw